# Overlapping shadows in material design vertical list

Tags: html, angularjs, css, material-design, angular-material

I'm using Material Design to implement an accordion-style list in HTML.  The list items have two states: closed and open.  As per Material guidelines, I'd like the items to have a small shadow when closed and a larger shadow when open.

The issue that I'm facing is that the shadow border is displaying between elements when the items are in the closed state.  I would simply put a `<div>` around the full list of items and put the shadow on that, but that would cause problems when a list item is expanded.  [See photo 2]  Any thoughts on how to solve this?

[Codeden Example](http://codepen.io/BirdInTheCity/pen/GJrmdY)

[image: Shadow issue]

On click, items should expand and come to the foreground.  This prevents me from putting a `<div>` tag around the full list.

[image: Expanded state]